# Perl- How do I insert a space before each capital letter except for the first occurrence or existing?

Tags: perl, space

I have a string like:

```
 SomeCamel WasEnteringText
```

I have found various means of splitting up the string and inserting spaces with php str_replace but, i need it in perl.

Sometimes there may be a space before the string, sometimes not. Sometimes there will be a space in the string but, sometimes not.

I tried:

```
    my $camel = "SomeCamel WasEnteringText";
    #or
    my $camel = " SomeCamel WasEntering Text";
    $camel =~ s/^[A-Z]/\s[A-Z]/g;
    #and
    $camel =~ s/([\w']+)/\u$1/g;
```

and many more combinations of =~s//g; after much reading.

I need a guru to direct this camel towards an oasis of answers.

OK, based on the input below I now have:

```
$camel =~ s/([A-Z])/ $1/g;
$camel =~ s/^ //; # Strip out starting whitespace
$camel =~ s/([^[:space:]]+)/\u$1/g;
```

Which gets it done but seems excessive. Works though.

Comment: P.S. I want the result to be "Some Camel Was Entering Text"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s/(?<!^)[A-Z][a-z]*+(?!\s+)\K/ /g;
```

And the less "screw this horsecrap" version:

```
s/
 (?<!^)          #Something not following the start of line,
    [A-Z][a-z]*+ #That starts with a capital letter and is followed by
                 #Zero or more lowercased letters, not giving anything back,
 (?!\s+)          #Not followed by one or more spaces,
\K               #Better explained here [1]
/ /gx;            #"Replace" it with a space.
```

EDIT: I noticed that this also adds extra whitespace when you add punctuation into the mix, which probably isn't what the OP wants; thankfully, the fix is simply changing the negative look ahead from \s+ to \W+. Although now I'm beginning to wonder why I actually added those pluses. Drats, me!

EDIT2: Erm, apologies, originally forgot the /g flag.

EDIT3: Okay, someone downvote me. I went retarded. No need for the negative lookbehind for ^ - I really dropped the ball on this one. Hopefully fixed:

```
s/[A-Z][a-z]*+(?!\W)\K/ /gx;
```

1: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: I tried $camel =~ s/(?<!^)[A-Z][a-z]*+(?!\s+)\K/ /; but I got a Nested quantifiers in regex error

Comment: Odd. Which version of Perl are you running? I tried it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, 5.12.1 in Windows, and 5.13.7 in Linux, but maybe it breaks down in some versions? If I recall, \K is a 5.10 addition, could that be it?

Comment: This should.. probably.. work on pre-5.10 versions, then. Can't test it though. s/([A-Z][a-z]*+(?!\W))/$1 /gx;

Comment: Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[A-Z][a-z]*+ <-- HERE (?!\W)K/

Comment: It never got to the \K, then. *+ (and ?+ and ++) are possessive qualifiers -- They eat, but never backtrack. 5.10 additions too, I suppose. EDIT: For what it's worth, s/([A-Z][a-z]*)(?=[A-Z]+)/$1 /g; should work on 5.8. Damn you, old Perl! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$camel =~ s/(?<! )([A-Z])/ $1/g; # Search for "(?<!pattern)" in perldoc perlre 
$camel =~ s/^ (?=[A-Z])//; # Strip out extra starting whitespace followed by A-Z
```

Please note that the obvious try of `$camel =~ s/([^ ])([A-Z])/$1 $2/g;` has a bug: it doesn't work if there are capital letters following one another (e.g. "ABCD" will be transformed into "ABCD" and not "A B C D")

Comment: @BipedalShark - misread the original Q... adjusted with the zero-width negative look-behind assertion.

Comment: The second match should instead be?

Comment: I have an instinctive aversion to seeing `[A-Z]` in patterns these days.  Unless it’s an RFC, `\p{Lu}` is more correct, and only one more character to type.

Comment: @tchrist - color me change-phobic old fart, but I find A-Z much more **readable** than `\p{Lu}`

Answer (score 0):

Try :
    s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/ /g

This inserts as space after a lower case character (ie not a space or start of string) and before and upper case character.

Comment: When I combine two: $camel =~ s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/ /g;
$camel =~ s/([^[:space:]]+)/\u$1/g; I get my desired result.

Comment: `\p{Lu}` is Uppercase Letter; `\p{Ll}` is Lowercase Letter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Improving ...

... on [Hughmeir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4434565/493648)'s, this works also with numbers and words starting with lower-case letters.

```
s/[a-z0-9]+(?=[A-Z])\K/ /gx
```

---

#### Tests

```
 myBrainIsBleeding     => my_Brain_Is_Bleeding
 MyBrainIsBleeding     => My_Brain_Is_Bleeding
 myBRAInIsBLLEding     => my_BRAIn_Is_BLLEding
 MYBrainIsB0leeding    => MYBrain_Is_B0leeding
 0My0BrainIs0Bleeding0 => 0_My0_Brain_Is0_Bleeding0
```