# How do I insert a space between an alpha character and a numeric character?

Tags: regex, perl, space

This is a continuation of my original question:
[Perl- How do I insert a space before each capital letter except for the first occurrence or existing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434439/perl-how-do-i-insert-a-space-before-each-capital-letter-except-for-the-first-occ)

I was able to achieve a desired result of inserting spaces between caps with only letters in the string:

```
my $camel ="SomeCamel IsEnteringText";
$camel =~ s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/ /g;
$camel =~ s/([^[:space:]]+)/\u$1/g;
```

Prints:

> Some Camel Is Entering Text

But, when numbers are present, I ran into issues:

```
my $camel ="Some 440Camel220 IsEntering100Text Nogo";
$camel =~ s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/ /g;
$camel =~ s/([^[:space:]]+)/\u$1/g;
```

Prints:

> Some 440Camel220 Is Entering100Text Nogo

Desired:

> Some 440 Camel 220 Is Entering 100 Text Nogo

So, how do I now insert a space between the letters and the numbers?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first substitution to be:

```
$camel =~ s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])/ /g;
```

See also [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: I voted this one as the answer because I only have to use two lines not four to get my desired result. Although I have to admit, I am still working on figuring out what is happening in there!

Comment: He is basically doing the same thing as my answer. The first half the grouping (separated by the `|`) matches transitions between lowercase letters and EITHER uppercase letters or digits, and the second half matches transitions between numbers and uppercase digits. This version will not turn `a440` into `a 440`; mine will. I don't know if that matters. I also think that the outermost `(?:...)` is unnecessary. In fact in this expression it is doing nothing.

Comment: I must spend some time and wrap my head around this. I think I am getting it a bit though. I am off to play with this until I will actually be able to write one myself (outside of single character replacements)! Thank you again...

Comment: @Matt: yes, grouping is unnecessary. Removing it from the re

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two substitutions:

```
$camel =~ s/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])/ /ig;
$camel =~ s/(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])/ /ig;
```

The first inserts a space at any transition between a digit and a letter. The `i` modifier at the end makes the expression case-insensitive. The second does the opposite.

Comment: Thank you, that worked well and I could understand what was going on. I wish I could select both yours and eugene y's as the answers because they are each as valuable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from last night, a 5.10+ solution,

```
$camel =~ s/(?:\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*+|[0-9]++)(?!\W)\K/ /g;
```

With the \p{} properties[1] that [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) had me rediscover : ) It's basically the same solution as last time, but now we check for numbers too.

1: http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-\p{}-and-\P{}